# How to bind many imageview to one imageview in android

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have one big imageview called- circle and more little imageviews called ivblue1-3.
I want that the circle imageview to rotate and all of the little imageviews to rotate together with him.
Unfortunately I do not know the bind between the imageviews.

The circle imageview is:

```
private ImageView mcircle = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.circle);
```

The little imageviews is:

```
private ImageView ivblue1=(ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.ivblue1);
private ImageView ivblue2=(ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.ivblue2);
private ImageView ivblue3=(ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.ivblue3);
```

I already have the XML that takes care of the rotate of the circle:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<rotate
    android:toDegrees="360"
    android:startOffset="0"
    android:repeatMode="restart"
    android:repeatCount="800"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:duration="3500"/>
</set>
```

Comment: Can you give an example please?

Comment: i don't have any, read the docs

Comment: I would love from someone else to  help me please

Comment: Is applying the same animation to Parent and child views and start them at the same time an option?

Comment: Both move but, it does not work together.

Comment: I still have no answer Would love for help